# Manually add unobtrusive validation to mvc form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This field is optionally validated based on its visibility. If the field is hidden then we don't want to validate it but if it's not hidden then I would want to add required validation.

I'm manually checking it now and stepping through the debugger I can see that the MS unobtrusive validation library is resetting the classes after I've changed the class attribute.

I'm guessing there's some built in methods I can call from the unobtrusive validation library but can't seem to get it figured out.

Model

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
[StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Url must be less than 151 characters.")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

View Javascipt

```
if ($("#Url").val() === '') {
    $('#Url').addClass('input-validation-error');
    return false;
} else {
    $('#Url').removeClass('input-validation-error');
}
```

View Form

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Url)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally found it!

Here's how to use the built-in validation library to add validation on the fly!

```
$('#Url').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just limit input length?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url, new { maxlength = 150 })
```

Ok, I haven't tried this but I think its roughly what you want

```
<div>
    @ Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
    @ If (Model.validateUrl)
      {
         var v = new ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Url);
         v.GetHtml();
      }
</div>
```

or it may just be as simple as

```
<div>
    @ Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
    @ If (Model.validateUrl)
      {
         @ Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Url)
      }
</div>
```

I can't quite recall which is the appropriate one, been working so much in angular lately

Comment: The length part isn't an issue, if the textbox is hidden it won't get over max length anyway. I need to make it required based on it's visibility.

Comment: sorry, I was looking at the length validation. What is the visibility based on? a viewmodel piece or something in the javascript?

Comment: Just another field on the model

Comment: I believe the model needs to have the Required attribute for the ValidationMessages method to work. Which would force it to be required either way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add class like that.  It will not work. You have to use  `$.validator`, so your code will be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Submitbutton")
        .click(function() {
            if ($("#Url").val() === '') {
                $.validator.setDefaults({
                    ignore: "#Url"
                });
            } else {
                $.validator.setDefaults({
                    ignore: null
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
</script>
```

If its value is null, it will ignore the validation.  Otherwise, it will display the validation error.

Comment: are you sure all the libraries are loaded properly ? and can you provide the whole javascript code?

Comment: They are loaded properly, the validation works fine for the rest of the form. The rest of the javascript is just that code posted above run in the OnSubmit handler.

Comment: can you check if this above code is giving any error because it worked with me

Comment: and try entering 151 characters and submit because your validation message shows when you enter 151 characters

Comment: let me know if it works and i made some changes in code its working now